What is the best way to cache paginated data when any page can be moved to and page size is changeable?
I have a React Redux web app that fetches data from an Express/Node backend and MySQL database. I have a table of records that I fetch and store in redux as an array of objects, which I display as a paginated table, and want to implement cacheable pagination. Currently, I use limit and offset and push the results to my array, which caches the data, however, this approach fails when trying to move to pages more than 1 page away; if I move to the third page from the first, I fetch a page of results, but since there's only two pages worth of results, nothing shows up on the third page. The obvious solution would be switching my array to an object whose keys are the page number, but then for a page size change I would have to empty the object and refetch the data. Is there any other approach to caching paginated data that would also work for page size changes?

Offset-based pagination on changing data is impossible to do consistently, so you also won't be able to find a good caching strategy. If the data can be assumed to stay the same, then caching may be possible. You're attempting to do caching inside your frontend's data model, replicating part of the DB state. This is powerful but difficult. An easier way is to just cache individual requests under a suitable cache key. For example, a REST API may be able to use the URL as a cache key. But yes, this would mean that changing the page size re-fetches data you already have.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm a little confused why caching paginated data is desirable. Splitting a large dataset into pages is usually done to circumvent performance problems. Caching data is also an attempt at solving performance problems. I'm not saying you shouldn't be caching paginated data, but it is a little odd to use two solutions to the same problem.
I don't see a reason to cache data when splitting it into pages provided that performance is good enough for the use case. Without any benchmarks for expected performance, I would opt to paginate without caching, and then measure the performance. If the pages are loading fast enough, then job done. Don't worry about this any further.
If performance of paginated data is actually problematic (note that a numerical difference in speed is not enough, does the user notice?) then I would do two things:

Measure the calls to fetch the data separately from the time it takes to render the new page. You want to make sure you are solving the right performance problem. Rendering the page itself could be the problem if fetching the new page of data goes quickly. This could imply a different approach than caching.

Consider loading the whole dataset into memory, and then calculating the indexes to show the user based on their page number and limit per page. You incur one network call, but navigating to other pages simply shows items from a different start index to a different end index in the array.


The trick with any performance optimization is to measure performance of various parts of your application so you can narrow down the part that is actually slow. The slow parts might surprise you. You've probably heard of this, but premature optimization is the root of all evil. Measure first, then optimize. That being said, try different approaches, and keep measuring performance. There is no secret sauce here. Solving performance problems involves experimentation and comparative analysis of different approaches.
So my answer really has become a bit of a frame-challenge: find the true source of the performance problem first before worrying about how to cache paginated data. You might be putting effort into the wrong solution, and caching paginated data might not be worth the engineering time to figure out all the kinks. Go with the solution that is easiest to implement first, measure, then reassess.

Thanks for the insight, Greg! Caching the paginated data was one of the desired outcomes when my supervisor was explaining the task to me, and we are switching from a system where we load the entire dataset and paginate on the frontend only because we want to keep with the redux ethos of only loading and keeping what we needed. My supervisor did mention that the caching would be kind of difficult and he was not sure of the industry standard way of handling this, so I will bring it up to him.

@Display212, yeah, there is no industry standard here. To be honest, there are very few "industry standards" for coding in software engineering. We always hope there is, because it makes solving the problem easier, but in my experience there are few universal solutions.
